# Error while deploying Ruby on Rails app with AWS Elastick Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails app with AWS Elastic Beanstalk running:- `eb create --service-role aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role`.

It gives me the next error:

> ERROR: NotFoundError - Elastic Beanstalk can't find a platform version
> that matches "64bit Amazon Linux 2 v3.4.6 running Ruby 2.7".

I have already successfully run:-
`eb init`.

My `ruby.config` file looks like that:

```yaml
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    RubyVersion: ruby-2.7
```

My `config.yml` file looks like that:

```yaml
branch-defaults:
  main:
    environment: learning-backend-dev
    group_suffix: null
global:
  application_name: learning-backend
  branch: null
  default_ec2_keyname: null
  default_platform: Ruby 2.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
  default_region: us-east-1
  include_git_submodules: true
  instance_profile: null
  platform_name: null
  platform_version: null
  profile: eb-cli
  repository: null
  sc: git
  workspace_type: Application
```